# Who are the people in the opening sequence of Mr Robot episode 1 season 1?

Tags: mr-robot

When the series starts, in the first scene, we see a group of people in the shadows discussing, as Elliot is narrating about the top 1% of the top 1%. In those people, I can only identify Tyrell Wellick.

Has anyone else from that scene been visualised as a character in the first two seasons? Is there a plan for them?

Comment: You are asking for spoilers.

Comment: @Rahul So they have not been revealed so far? I have seen all episodes of season 1 and 2, I just cannot link any other character to those

Comment: Let me give you a hint. _The one who committed suicide._

Comment: I don't know that any of them are explicitly named, but I believe we are meant to assume that they are other executive leaders at Evil Corp.

Comment: @Rahul Ah yes, completely forgot how he looked like.

Comment: @ViggyNash So we will not see them? I am just asking in the case of I saw them but did not notice them (like Rahul pointed out one of them)

Comment: I had assumed it was Wellick's team of lawyers that Eliot meets at the end of the episode when Wellick summons him to offer him a job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *There’s a powerful group of people out there that are secretly running
>   the world. I’m talking about the guys no one knows about, the guys
>   that are invisible. The top 1% of the top 1%, the guys that play God
>   without permission. And now I think they’re following me.*

[image: Screenshot of the beginning of Mr. Robot S01E01, showing the group of men in focus]

This scene at the beginning of the first episode of Mr. Robot, '*eps1.0_hellofriend.mov*', is continued at the very end, and the start of the second episode: it is the group of men awaiting the arrival of Elliot Alderson (the man on the far left strangely seems to be missing in the later scenes, though).

We have a clearer picture of them at the start of episode 2, however:

[image: Screenshot of the beginning of Mr. Robot S01E02, showing the group of men sitting down, staring at Elliot]

Apart from Tyrell Wellick, not one of them is recognizable as a recurring character - which is logical, considering who they are. They are introduced to Elliot by Wellick:

> I'm sorry to bring you in like this: technically what we're doing
>   might be considered illegal, which is why I'm surrounded by **eleven
>   of our most annoying lawyers**.